# C++17 map emplace without default constructor (private default constructor)

Tags: c++, c++17, stdmap

I like to emplace a object into a map with a private default constructor. So find out that following code not work:

```
class DB {
public:
    DB(std::string user, std::string password,
        std::string db, std::string host, unsigned int port = 3306);

    static DB& instance(
             std::string const& session_name,
             std::string const& user = "user",
             std::string const& password = "password",
             std::string const& db = "database",
             std::string const& host = "localhost",
             unsigned int port = 3306) {
         auto instance = database_instances.find(session_name);

         if (instance == database_instances.end()) {
             //database_instances.emplace(session_name, user, password, db, host, port);
             //database_instances.insert( std::unordered_map< std::string, DB >::value_type ( session_name, DB{user, password, db, host, port}));
             database_instances.emplace(std::piecewise_construct,
                                  std::forward_as_tuple(session_name),
                                  std::forward_as_tuple(user, password, db, host, port));
         }
        return database_instances[session_name];
    }

    static std::shared_ptr<DB> instance(
            std::string const& session_name);

    static DB& instance();

    ~DB() = default;

private:
    DB() = default;

    DB(const DB& );

    DB & operator = (const DB &);

    /** fields: user, password ... **/

    static std::map<std::string, DB> database_instances;
};
```

Is there a way in C++ to do this with a private default constructor?

Comment: What's the error message that you are getting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure that the line giving the error is not this one:

```
   return database_instances[session_name];
```

rather than the call to `emplace`?

That line will attempt to default construct a value of `DB` in the case where the key does not exist in the map.